# Cannot run laravel-echo-server using pm2

Tags: laravel, pm2, laravel-echo

I'm trying to run `laravel-echo-server` using `PM2` but it throws following error:

> ```
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] online
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] starting in -fork mode-
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] online
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] starting in -fork mode-
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] online
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] starting in -fork mode-
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:25: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] online
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:26: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:26: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] starting in -fork mode-
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:26: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] online
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:26: PM2 log: App [my-app:3] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
> PM2        | 2020-07-20T17:00:26: PM2 log: Script C:\USERS\HP\APPDATA\ROAMING\NPM\LARAVEL-ECHO-SERVER.CMD had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
>
> C:\Users\HP\.pm2\logs\laravel-queue-worker-out-1.log last 15 lines:
> C:\Users\HP\.pm2\logs\laravel-queue-worker-error-1.log last 15 lines:
> C:\Users\HP\.pm2\logs\my-app-out-3.log last 15 lines:
> C:\Users\HP\.pm2\logs\my-app-error-3.log last 15 lines:
> 3|my-app   | C:\USERS\HP\APPDATA\ROAMING\NPM\LARAVEL-ECHO-SERVER.CMD:1
> 3|my-app   | @ECHO off
> 3|my-app   | ^
> 3|my-app   | 
> 3|my-app   | SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
> 3|my-app   |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
> 3|my-app   |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
> 3|my-app   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
> 3|my-app   |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
> 3|my-app   |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
> 3|my-app   |     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:32:23)
> 3|my-app   |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
> 3|my-app   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
> 3|my-app   |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
> 3|my-app   |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
> ```

here is my `.yml` config file:

```
apps:
  - name: my-app
    script: laravel-echo-server
    instances: 1
    args:
      - start
```

to run the process, I'm using following command:

```
pm2 start echo-server-file.yml
```

Please help me to get out of this issue.

Thanks in advance.